# MySQL Query to get individual item from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables- 1. Feed 2. Seller

Feed table is like this

```
seller_id       item_id     end_date
=========       =======     =========
1               1           2017-02-12[A future date]
1               2           2017-03-12[A future date]
1               3           2017-01-12[A past date]
2               12          2017-02-12[A future date]
3               123         2017-01-10[A past date]
```

Seller table is like this

```
seller_id
=========
1
2
3
```

I like to get the result like this where end_date is greater than or equal to Current Date and I need only a single item_id for each seller_id-

```
seller_id       item_id
=========       =======
1               1 or 2
2               12
```

And my SQL Query is like-

```
SELECT S.seller_id, R.item_id FROM Feed F, Seller S WHERE S.seller_id=F.seller_id AND F.end_date>=CURDATE() GROUP BY S.seller_id LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY on `feed`. And 1 or 2 ??? Which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min()`, or `max()`, or even `any_value()` aggregate function with a `group by` clause to select a `item_id` per seller:

```
SELECT S.seller_id, max(R.item_id)
FROM Feed F
INNER JOIN Seller S on S.seller_id=F.seller_id
WHERE F.end_date>=CURDATE()
GROUP BY S.seller_id
```

It depends on your exact business requirements which function to use.

Answer (score 1):

Check this..

```
    SELECT S.seller_id, MAX(R.item_id) AS item_id 
    FROM Feed F, Seller S 
    WHERE S.seller_id=F.seller_id 
    AND F.end_date>=CURDATE() 
    GROUP BY S.seller_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need the table Feed, you will group by id_seller after having selected items with enddate greater than current date. Then select a unique item_id by some aggregate function of your choice ( max() here). Here is an exemple of your request :

```
SELECT
    F.seller_id,
    max(F.itemid)
FROM
    Feed F
WHERE
    F.end_date > CURRENT_DATE

GROUP BY
    F.seller_id
```